# Blackberry GPRS not working

Tags: blackberry, wifi, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, gprs

I have one BlackBerry Application which is running perfectly fine with wi-fi. but I am not able to run the application using GPRS. please help me..Thanks..

```java
boolean hasConnectivity_BIS = TransportInfo.isTransportTypeAvailable(TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_BIS_B)&&TransportInfo.hasSufficientCoverage(TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_BIS_B);
boolean hasConnectivity_MDS = TransportInfo.isTransportTypeAvailable(TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_MDS)&&TransportInfo.hasSufficientCoverage(TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_MDS);
boolean hasConnectivity_TCP_Cell = TransportInfo.isTransportTypeAvailable(TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_CELLULAR)&&TransportInfo.hasSufficientCoverage(TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_CELLULAR);
boolean hasConnectivity_TCP_wifi = TransportInfo.isTransportTypeAvailable(TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_WIFI)&&TransportInfo.hasSufficientCoverage(TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_TCP_WIFI);
boolean hasConnectivity_WAP = TransportInfo.isTransportTypeAvailable(TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_WAP)&&TransportInfo.hasSufficientCoverage(TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_WAP);
boolean hasConnectivity_WAP2 = TransportInfo.isTransportTypeAvailable(TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_WAP2)&&TransportInfo.hasSufficientCoverage(TransportInfo.TRANSPORT_WAP2);

if (hasConnectivity_BIS||hasConnectivity_MDS||hasConnectivity_TCP_Cell||hasConnectivity_TCP_wifi||hasConnectivity_WAP||hasConnectivity_WAP2)
{
    boolean hasconn=ButtonPay.checkConnection();
    System.out.println("Has Connection?????>>> "+hasconn);
    //my implementation    
}
else
{
    caller.showDialog("Response", "Internet connection not available");
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do to run it on GPRS.

Comment: Please post the code where you configure the transport types in the `ConnectionFactory` and also the timeouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append your connection type after your URL.

```java
public static String getConnectionString() {

    String connectionString = null;

    // Simulator behaviour is controlled by the USE_MDS_IN_SIMULATOR
    // variable.
    if (DeviceInfo.isSimulator()) {

        connectionString = ";deviceside=true";
    }

    // Wifi is the preferred transmission method
    else if (WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED) {

        connectionString = ";interface=wifi";
    }

    // Is the carrier network the only way to connect?
    else if ((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) {

        String carrierUid = getCarrierBIBSUid();

        if (carrierUid == null) {
            // Has carrier coverage, but not BIBS. So use the carrier's TCP
            // network

            connectionString = ";deviceside=true";
        } else {
            // otherwise, use the Uid to construct a valid carrier BIBS
            // request

            connectionString = ";deviceside=false;connectionUID="+carrierUid + ";ConnectionType=mds-public";
        }
    }

    // Check for an MDS connection instead (BlackBerry Enterprise Server)
    else if ((CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) {

        connectionString = ";deviceside=false";
    }

    // If there is no connection available abort to avoid hassling the user
    // unnecssarily.
    else if (CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus() == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_NONE) {
        connectionString = "none";

    }

    // In theory, all bases are covered by now so this shouldn't be reachable.But hey, just in case ...
    else {

        connectionString = ";deviceside=true";
    }

    return connectionString;
}

/**
 * Looks through the phone's service book for a carrier provided BIBS
 * network
 * 
 * @return The uid used to connect to that network.
 */
private synchronized static String getCarrierBIBSUid() {
    ServiceRecord[] records = ServiceBook.getSB().getRecords();
    int currentRecord;

    for (currentRecord = 0; currentRecord < records.length; currentRecord++) {
        if (records[currentRecord].getCid().toLowerCase().equals("ippp")) {
            if (records[currentRecord].getName().toLowerCase()
                    .indexOf("bibs") >= 0) {
                return records[currentRecord].getUid();
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Once you writtent this code. use

```java
con = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url + getConnectionString());
```

It will determine available network type .

Comment: @Shanshak Agarwal..Thanks a lot..I am trying this code.and reply you very soon and also will accept as solution if it works and i am editing my code pls look it the code..

Comment: This is the legacy approach and should not be used for devices running OS 5.0 and higher. Instead, the new `ConnectionFactory` class is preferable, since it's much more easier to use, produces cleaner code and is less likely to introduce errors (both in coding and execution).

Comment: @MisterSmith..Thanks a lot for Reply. But I have used this code because I want to run this Application on OS 5.0. I will see about ConnectionFactory class also. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @RiddhiBarbhaya, the [ConnectionFactory works on OS 5.0](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/transport/ConnectionFactory.html).  It is only unavailable **before** 5.0.

Comment: @RiddhiBarbhaya, I edited this answer, to properly indent and activate syntax highlighting on the code, to make it more readable.  You just undid my edit.  **Do not** do this.

Comment: @ShashankAgarwal.. I have implemented your code in My Application and It is under Testing Now. As App is Tested on Real Device, I will definately get back to you and Accept answer as Solution for sure. Even I am also waitng...Thanks a lot...